# RedmineMySQL not starting

Tags: mysql, windows, service, redmine

Kindly note that the redmineMySQL services is not running and I am not able to start it. Everytime I try to start I get the following in the server.err log file, the 1067 windows error. Please assist.

Thanks a lot.

```
140603 10:57:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

140603 10:57:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

140603 10:57:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

140603 10:57:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

140603 10:57:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M

140603 10:57:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

140603 10:57:54 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.

140603 10:57:54  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start

140603 10:57:55 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 38540871

140603 10:57:55 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306

140603 10:57:55 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';

140603 10:57:55 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.

140603 10:57:55 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory

140603 10:57:55 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?

140603 10:57:55 [ERROR] Aborting



140603 10:57:55  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...

140603 10:57:56  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 38540871

140603 10:57:56 [Note] C:\BitNami\redmine-2.2.2-0\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306

Comment: Yes SQLEXPRESS was dynamic and after the restart it reserved port 3306. Thanks Kayasax.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the port of the SQLEXPRESS server to a specific value as it was dynamic and reserved port 3306.